# Can I ask this question about book publishers?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to find this children's sci-fi book I read about 20 years ago. I've asked a question, but it's not met any success, so I'd like to try a new tact.

Can I ask for a list of known US publishers of children's sci-fi and fantasy publishers from the 80s and 90s? Publishers like Scholastic Apple Paperbacks.

Comment: my gut tells me it'd be closed as a list question

Comment: @phantom42 List questions aren't globally off topic, especially when so limited in scope and purely objective. I'd be comfortable relying on the community and meta if it came up. My concern is whether or not asking about sci-fi book *publishers* is on topic.

Comment: Most publishers are in the category of Childrens books OR sci-fi and fantasy. Not sure if there is a single one that specializes in both combined.

Comment: I didn't say that they were globally off-topic. I think asking *about* publishers is, but I'm not sure how asking for a potentially very large list of publishers is.

Answer (score 3):

No. Although this list question is technically finite, the reality is that it's liable to be a very large number which makes it an inherently bad fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Wikipedia puts it very nicely on their own page about [Scifi Publishers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_publishers);

> This is an incomplete list that may never be able to satisfy
>   particular standards for completeness.

Comment: I don't think the list would be very large. To be in it the publishing company would have had to exist in the 80s & 90s, been a children's book publisher and not an adult book publisher, had to have published scifi and fantasy fiction (not just stuff like Hatchet and Babysitter's Club). I've got a small list I'm working on already,though, so I suppose it'll have to suffice.